# What is the best way communication between threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, retrofit, android-handler

Actually I am using retrofit inside of project , and I am calling 2 Aysnc requests. but I need that after this requests success to trigger other method. how to know when this request are done and then trigger other method ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use async Task in android. Here's some important highlights

create an async task

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { ... }
```

it will have 4 methods that you can override.

```
onPreExecute()
doInBackground(Params...)
onProgressUpdate(Progress...)
onPostExecute(Result)
```

basically, you just need to put the method that you wanna trigger in the onPostExecute method.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    //add your method here
}
```

for more details please refer to android documentation on AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html